# INFO nova.consoleauth.manager [req-db1e6559-91c4-4412-b908-c323aae1161a - - - - -] Checking Token: bb41fdbe-5cf3-4627-9ba1-7d48849caf22, False

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-horizon

I created a VM in the dashboard, it can not use the web-terminal , telling the error:

> Failed to connect to server (code: 1006)

[image: image description]

But in my `/etc/nova/nova.conf`, I think there is no misconfiguration:

```
[vnc]
enabled = True
vncserver_listen = 0.0.0.0
vncserver_proxyclient_address = 192.168.8.102
novncproxy_base_url = http://45.117.40.168:6080/vnc_auto.html
```

the `192.168.8.102` is the `ha-node2`'s  management-ip.

abd attention my compute node2 also is this node.

And in the `/var/log/nova/nova-consoleauth.log`, when I turn to this web page, there only this below log:

```
INFO nova.consoleauth.manager [req-db1e6559-91c4-4412-b908-c323aae1161a - - - - -] Checking Token: bb41fdbe-5cf3-4627-9ba1-7d48849caf22, False
```

---

**Edit-1**

Attention, the computer-node1 and the controller-node1 are the same node, the computer-node2 and the controller-node2 are the same node too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the ip in the same subnet.

compute node 10.x.x.21

```
[vnc]
vncserver_listen=$my_ip
vncserver_proxyclient_address=$my_ip
novncproxy_base_url=http://10.x.x.22:6080/vnc_auto.html
```

controller node 10.x.x.22

```
[vnc]
vncserver_listen=$my_ip
vncserver_proxyclient_address=$my_ip
novncproxy_port=6080
```

Comment: See my Edit-1, my controller2 and compute2 are the same node.

Comment: change 192.168.8.102 to 45.117.40.168? or any error in /var/log/nova/nova-novncproxy.log?

Comment: I found if I click "click this to enter the terminal", then I refresh serval times, I will get the Terminal.